# Iterating through columns of a table in a database and printing number of records in it

Tags: python, mysql, database, aggregate-functions

Iterating through columns of a table in a database and printing number of records in it

already connected to the database, need to iterate through the columns of a table and prints count of records in each archive as name is printed below

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
try:
   mySQLconnection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                    database='nmoorg',
                                   user='root',
                                   password='ChvU5M12')
   sql_select_Query = "select * from archive"
   cursor = mySQLconnection .cursor()
   cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
   records = cursor.fetchall()
   print("Total number of rows in python_developers is - ",  cursor.rowcount)
   print ("Printing each row's column values i.e.  developer record")

   for row in records:
       print("archive name = ", row[1], )

   cursor.close()

except Error as e :
    print ("Error while connecting to MySQL", e )
finally:
    #closing database connection.
    if(mySQLconnection .is_connected()):
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

I need to count the number of records in a column instead of table

Comment: Can you provide a sample row from your table? I don't understand what you mean by number of records in a column instead of table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) num FROM archive
```

is the way to count rows in a table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) num, COUNT(column) num_column FROM archive
```

is the way to count both all the rows and the number of rows with a non-null value in `archive.column`.

I guess that's what you mean by *count the number of records in a column instead of table*.

Counting by doing `SELECT *` and counting the rows in the result set is shockingly inefficient. Plus, `.fetchall()` will blow out your RAM if the table has any interesting size. The whole point of SQL is to allow you to handle data sets orders of magnitude larger than your RAM.